# dml query within WITH sql

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql, common-table-expression

I was just supposing that I could put a `set query` within `WITH` statement in SQL Server 2008.

So I wrote a few lines of code:

```
with temp as   
(
    SELECT row_number() OVER (ORDER BY [ShareItems].ItemId) AS Row, ItemId FROM [ShareItems]
)
set @row = ItemId //<---error
```

but I am getting an error above, but in case of `select` statement using `WITH` keyword, there was no error???

```
with temp as   
(
    SELECT 
        row_number() OVER (ORDER BY [ShareItems].ItemId) AS Row, ItemId 
    FROM [ShareItems]
)
SELECT ItemId 
FROM temp //<--- OK (no error)
```

Any suggestion ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this way:

```
with temp as   
(
  SELECT row_number() OVER (ORDER BY [ShareItems].ItemId) AS Row, ItemId 
  FROM [ShareItems]
)

select  @row = ItemId from temp
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
with temp as   
    (
        SELECT row_number() OVER (ORDER BY [ShareItems].ItemId) AS Row, ItemId FROM [ShareItems]
    )
SELECT @row = ItemId FROM temp
```